# How many iterations Newton's method needs

Tags: newton-raphson

$g(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x - \frac{a}{x^2})$, $a > 1$ and $a<100$, if $a>0$ then $1<10^{2k}a<100$. So that 
$\sqrt{a}=\sqrt{10^{-2k}10^{2k}a} = 10^{-k}\sqrt{10^{2k}a}$.
$x_0 = \min(a,10)$, $\forall a >0 $ $\exists k \in Z$ so that $10^{2k}a \in [1,100]$.

How can i find the number of iterations for Newton's method to find $\sqrt{a}$ with accuracy $10^{-8}$? I need some pointer as of where to start this.

Comment: You can have a look at [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/558145/minimum-number-of-iterations-in-newtons-method-to-find-a-square-root).

Comment: That link helped a bit, althoug i dont get where did he get those formulas in the beginning. And i have absolute accuaraccy he uses relative accuaraccy.

Comment: The formulas are found solving a peculiar recurrence. Have a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsIteration.html) for example. You should find this in standard numerical calculus book (sorry but I've only pointers in Italien in mind at present).

Comment: but the part about (1+2^-b)sqrt(y) from what is this derived from?

Comment: I don't see that... can you be more precise?

Comment: In the first link "if you want to achieve 2^−b relative accuracy, xn=(1+2^−b)sqrt(y)". This part. and can i use this for absolute accuaracy?

Comment: No in this case, you should use $x_n-\sqrt{y}=2^{-b}$

Comment: Making some advancments, but if i use the xn-sqrt(y) then i cant get rid of the sqrt(y) in the first element. And how should i calculate the second element if my a is between 1 and 100 and x0 is between 1 on 10?